# How to go Kulu Manali from Gujarat?

Tags: public-transport, india

How can I get to Kulu Manali from Gujarat? I can leave from either Ahmedabad or Bhavnagar.

Comment: *Please give all options for that.* - And if we don't?

Comment: The question is a bit terse, but I don't think this is unsalvageably off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want all the options?  *All* the options? [You can't handle all the options](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5j2F4VcBmeo)!

Or if you think you can, check out Rome 2 Rio:

- http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Ahmedabad/Kullu
- http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Ahmedabad/Manali
- http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Bhavnagar/Kullu
- http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Bhavnagar/Manali

Comment: Give me at least 10 good options. Thanks in advance ...

Comment: See the links above?  Click on them, my friend.

Comment: Yes I do it. I just want to ask for other options you have ...

Comment: See the right side panel on those pages, with "Fly", "Train", "Bus" etc?  They're already offering you a dozen options for each pair of places!

Comment: I wonder if teleportation is an option

Answer (score 0):

Travel from Ahmedabad to Delhi via air or train.
From Delhi ISBT Kashmere Gate, you will get buses to Manali.